# Winter Bash 2015の季節がやってきました

Tags: 討議, winter-bash

年末が近づいて来ましたので、寒い・暗い日々をもっと楽しく過ごすためにWinter Bashを開催します！

[image: header]

今日から来年の1月3日まで、いつもどおりにサイトを利用すると自分のアイコンに被れる帽子をもらえます！過去に英語版のサイトで参加したかもしれませんが、今年は新しい帽子を準備しています。

バッジと似たようなものですが、バッジと違って帽子はユーザーアイコンに被ることができるので、バッジよりも楽しめるでしょう。帽子の一覧と獲得方法は[Winter Bash ページ](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com)に書かれています。合計28個のうち、あなたは何個獲得できるでしょうか？そして秘密の帽子もあります。何個あるのかはヒ・ミ・ツ！

帽子を獲得すると、プロフィールのアクティビティタブに以下のような帽子が表示されます。これをクリックすることで、どの帽子をかぶるかを選択できます。

[image: bobble]

（バッジが寒くなるといけないので、この青い帽子は被れません）

[image: dialog]

帽子を選択したら、プロフィール写真と合うようにサイズや位置を変えることができます。

[image: controls]

Winter Bash中はヘッダに雪の結晶が表示され、帽子関連の通知がここに集まります：

[image: topbarNotif]

「帽子なんて嫌い！」と思う方もいるでしょう。もし参加したくなかったら雪の結晶をクリックして、

[image: topbarSnowflake]

左下の「帽子が嫌い」というリンクをクリックしてください。この設定はイベント中何度でも変更できます。

なお、集めた帽子は Winter Bash が終わると消えてしまいます。さあ、帽子を探しに行きましょう！