# Winter Bash とは何ですか？

Tags: サポート, winter-bash

しばらくすると Winter Bash なる物が[始まる](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/)そうで、他のコミュニティでは[奇妙な投票](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4251/118664)を行なったりしている様子です。
[去年の様子](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2081/3054)を見ると、帽子で遊んでいるのは解るのですが、そもそもこれは何なのでしょうか。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stack Exchange ネットワークで毎年この時期にやっているイベントです。

> The year is rapidly coming to a close, which means even though we typically [hate it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268583/164200), it’s time to have some fun...with hats!  That’s right - **it’s time for Winter Bash 2016!!**
>   <sub>--- SE社の bluefeet さんからモデレーターに届いたメールより引用</sub>

特定の日に質問を投稿する、スコアnを獲得する、n回投票する、などの条件を達成することで「帽子」がもらえます。バッジと似たような仕組みですが、この帽子は自分のアイコンに被せて表示することができ、他のユーザーにも帽子をかぶったアイコンが表示されます。

今年は12/19～1/8に開催され、期間が過ぎれば帽子は全て消えます。

この企画に参加するかどうかはサイトごとに選べるため、サイトによっては奇妙な？投票を行っているようです。またユーザーが圧倒的に多い本家 Stack Overflow だけは、無効化はしないもののオプトイン制になっています。

Comment: 解り易い回答ありがとうございます。欧米には元となる帽子にまつわる習俗などがあるのかな、とも考えたのですが、そういう訳ではなさそうですね。

Comment: @mjy XBoxのアバターカスタマイズ機能を参考にしたとか https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/12/welcome-to-winter-bash-2012/ 、社内でご褒美に帽子をプレゼントする習慣があるとか https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CDi_nj1-G6U どうとか。後者は今回限りの冗談かもしれませんが。