# Winter Bash 2017 の季節です

Tags: サポート, winter-bash

毎年 Stack Exchange では、年末の時期に Winter Bash というイベントが開催されます。

Winter Bash では、特定の条件を満たすことで **帽子** を手に入れることができます。手に入れた帽子は、期間限定で被ることもできます！

PC で見た場合、サイトの右上のアイコンから帽子の情報を得ることができます。

[image: PC で ja.meta.stackoverflow.com を閲覧した場合の右上の画像です。いくつかアイコンが並んでいる中で、右から2つ目のアイコンが雪の結晶の形をしています。このアイコンをクリックすると Winter Bash の説明が出てきます。]

今年の帽子に関して公表されている情報は、[こちらから確認できます。](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/)

しかし例年、説明されない隠れた帽子も存在します。また、日本語だと帽子の名前のネタが分かりづらいものも存在します。

Winter Bash をより楽しむため、帽子の情報について教えてください！

### 参考リンク

- [Winter Bash 2017: Greatest <strike>Hits</strike> Hats!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/12/12/winter-bash-2017-greatest-hits-hats/) -- Stack Overflow Blog
- [Winter Bash 2017 Hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304340/341401) -- Stack Exchange Meta
- ja.SO における過去の Winter Bash

  - [Winter Bash 2016 の帽子](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2387/19110)
  - [Winter Bash 2015の季節がやってきました](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2081/19110)
- [Winter Bash 2017 自体についての、日本語によるもっと詳しい解説](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2624/19110)

Answer (score 3):

### シークレット帽子

ここにリストされているもの以外にもあるかもしれません。また、書かれている情報が間違っていたり、それでは足りなかったりするかもしれません。

#### Ooh, Shiny!

[image: 青いキャップ帽の前面に、シンプルかつ幾何学的な模様が描いてあります。]

> 条件: 質問にクローズ票か削除表を投じ、クローズか削除された。
>  背景: ???

#### Cosmic Brain

[image: 1つの大きい惑星と、3つの小さい惑星が回っているような図です]

> 条件: 「いい回答」バッジを獲得する(10点以上)
>  背景: 銀河系かつプラス票が条件となっている。

#### Galaxy Brain

[image: 銀河の絵です]

> 条件: 「すごい回答」バッジを獲得する(25点以上)
>  背景: 銀河系かつプラス票が条件となっている。

#### Universe Brain

[image: 銀河の中心から後光のようなものが差している絵です]

> 条件: 「もっとすごい回答」バッジを獲得する(100点以上)
>  背景: 銀河系かつプラス票が条件となっている。

#### Rep Cap

[image: 灰色のニット帽の前面にアルファベットで REP と書かれています]

> 条件: その名の通り、信用度の上限に達する
>  背景: reputation capacity と cap を掛けている
>  
>  [I received the reputation cap hat before hitting the reputation cap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304387/341401) によると、上限に達しなくても 200 rep/day を超えれば獲得できるようです。

#### Row Of Many Candles

[image: ９本のロウソクの意匠が付いています。ハヌッキーヤー？]

> 期間限定: どこかが12月20日の時に投票or質問or回答などのアクションをする
>  背景: 今年のハヌカーは12月12日から8日間。でも20日って終わった日の次の日だよね？
>  
>  正確にはUTC+14:00が12月20日の時からUTC−12:00が12月20日の時まで。換算すると2017年12月19日19:00から2017年12月21日21:00までとなる。
>  なおこの期間限定帽子、重複して入手した場合開始日時の遅い方から入手した事になる。

#### Some Kind Of Sun Thingy

[image: 被ると頭から太陽が出ているようにも見えます。]

> 期間限定: どこかが12月21日の時に投票or質問or回答などのアクションをする
>  背景: 今年の冬至は21日16:28(UTC)。
>  
>  正確にはUTC+14:00が12月21日の時からUTC−12:00が12月21日の時まで。換算すると2017年12月20日19:00から2017年12月22日21:00までとなる。

#### Red Hat With White Fur Trim

[image: もふもふのサンタ帽ですね。]

> 期間限定: どこかが12月25日の時に投票or質問or回答などのアクションをする
>  背景: その日はクリスマス。24日と25日の間にサンタがやってくるのです。
>  
>  正確にはUTC+14:00が12月25日の時からUTC−12:00が12月25日の時まで。換算すると2017年12月24日19:00から2017年12月26日21:00までとなる。

#### Glasses With A Number On Top

[image: 2018と書かれたメガネ。]

> 期間限定: どこかが1月1日0時ちょうどの時にチャットで発言、かつそれに☆をつけてもらう
>  親サイトが無いチャット部屋では貰えないちょっとむなしい帽子。
>  
>  換算すると2017年12月31日21:00から2018年1月1日21:00までとなる。

Answer (score 1):

### 公開されている帽子

#### IDENTIFICATION DIVISION

[image: 灰色と藍色の帽子と、黄土色の眼鏡]

条件: 銀バッジを獲得する
背景: ???

#### The Mad Hatter

[image: 黒いシルクハットに赤毛、それとまだら模様の蝶ネクタイです]

条件: 投稿にコメントすることなく、1日(UTC)以内に5回編集または編集の提案をおこなった
背景: マッド・ハッターは『不思議の国のアリス』の登場人物

#### Foot of the Rainbow

[image: エメラルド色の耳が2つと、エメラルド色の角が1本あります]

条件: 金バッジを獲得する
背景: ユニコーン(空想上の生き物)

#### Just Jesting

[image: 色とりどりなピエロ帽です]

条件: 10個のコメントにそれぞれプラス票がついた
背景: ???

#### Explorer

条件: 投稿した回答が承認され、かつそれ以外の投票が12時間以内に1つもない
背景: ???

#### Too Cool

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

条件: Android・iOSアプリで７件の投稿に投票する
背景: ???

#### The Milliner

[image: 中世の婦人が被るような、薄い赤紫色の丸い帽子です。帽子の上にリボンやボタンなどの飾りが施されています]

条件: 11個の帽子を集める
背景: ???

#### Hero Of Time

[image: 緑のバンダナから金髪が見えています]

条件: 午後7時に質問を投稿（どのタイムゾーンでも可）
背景: 『ゼルダの伝説』のリンク

[What's wrong with the “Hero Of Time” Hat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304349/341401) によると、投稿した質問が up-vote を受けることも条件らしい。

#### Sherlock

[image: 茶色い帽子に虫眼鏡が立てかけてあります]

条件: 自分の質問に回答し、質問と回答の両方がスコア+3以上になった
背景: シャーロック・ホームズ

#### Taco Tuesday Any Day

条件: スコア+3以上の回答を5つ投稿する
背景: ???

#### Werewolf Hunter

[image: 黒いハット帽と、黒いクロスボウです]

条件: 1年以上前に投稿された質問5件を編集する
背景: ???

#### Like Clockwork

条件: UTC時間で10日間連続してサイトにアクセスした
背景: ???

#### Think!

[image: 黒い蝶ネクタイです]

条件: 6個のそれぞれ別の質問・回答について、コメントした後に投稿者によって編集された
背景: ???

#### Fashionable

条件: Winter Bash 期間中に投稿した質問について、計9000回以上閲覧された
背景: ???

#### Silencium

条件: コメントのついていない質問に回答し、回答にもコメントがつかないままスコアが7以上になった
背景: ???

#### Brunhilde

条件: Stack Overflow（英語版）以外、15日間以内に3つのネットワークサイトで信用度150点以上を集める
背景: ???

#### It’s-a me!

[image: 赤い帽子の下に口ひげがあります。赤い帽子の前面には白い丸の模様があります。]

条件: コメントした後に投稿者が投稿を編集し、コメントは削除（自分のもの以外の投稿に限る）
背景: 『スーパーマリオブラザーズ』のマリオ

#### This Is Fine

[image: 犬の顔の下で火が燃えています]

条件: 2017年、かつWinter Bash開始以前に投稿したコメントを10個削除
背景: ???

#### I’ll Handle It

[image: 化学の実験眼鏡のような平たい眼鏡です]

条件: 質問のクローズに投票し、クローズ後に編集、その後リオープンに投票
背景: ???

#### Fascinator

条件: 3日間連続(UTC)でサイトの検索機能を利用する
背景: ???

#### Waffles

条件: -3以下の質問に+5スコア以上の回答を投稿した後、質問がスコア+3以上になる
背景: ???

#### And YOU Get A Hat!

[image: 中世オペラ歌手のようなモフモフの黒髪です]

条件: みんなが獲得した帽子が20種類に達し、そのうち1つを持っている
背景: ???

#### Extra Toppings

条件: 既に承認済み回答のある質問に対し、新たに回答してスコア+3に達した
背景: ???