# Winter Bash 2017: Greatest Hats ー 帽子の季節です！

Tags: 討議, winter-bash

北半球では気温が落ち込み、グレゴリオ暦上の新年がどんどん近づいている今日この頃。スタック・オーバーフロー、それにStack Exchangeネットワークサイトの何万というアバターたちの耳も冷たくなってきました。ということは…そう、帽子の出番です！

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

それもただの帽子ではありません。今回はWinter Bash 6<sup>1</sup>周年を記念して、過去の開催年でも人気の高かった帽子たちが返り咲きを果たします。帽子集めをもっと長く楽しめるよう、獲得条件の見直しもおこないました。（そして、よくよく探せば新登場の帽子も見つかるかもしれません！）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

さあ、ちょっとしたお洒落で冬を楽しむ準備はいかがでしょうか。[Winter Bash参加サイト](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network) で [特定のチャレンジ](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com) をクリアすると、条件に応じた帽子を手に入れることができます。帽子をかぶると、アバターが表示される場所ではどこでも、どのサイトでも反映されます。獲得した帽子をかぶるには、自分のプロフィールページを開きましょう。どこのサイトでも構いません。そしてバッジの概要欄を飾っている帽子をクリックします：

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

すると帽子ボックスが開きます：

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

帽子を選ぶと同時に、アバターにフィットするよう位置・サイズを調整することもできます：

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Winter Bashは、Stack Exchangeネットワーク全体でちょっぴりリラックスして遊びを楽しむ、年一度の機会です。ですが、羽目を外しつつも、スタック・オーバーフローとStack Exchangeにはそうした雰囲気を持ち込みたくないという方への配慮は怠りたくないと思います：これまで通り、トップバーにある雪の結晶マークのメニューから「帽子は嫌い」を選ぶことで、Winter Bashをオフにすることができます。

参加するみなさんが帽子をゲットできる期間は、2017年12月13日から2018年1月2日までです。1月2日を最後に、あれだけ楽しんだ帽子も全て倉庫行き、また見ることはないでしょう… でもまた<strike>5</strike> 6年後、Greatest Hatsがまた帰ってこないとも限りません！

---

1 豆知識：帽子プロジェクトの設計担当グループでは当初、Greatest HatsをWinter Bash 5周年を祝うイベントとして計画していました。それから [指折り数える](https://stackpromos.com) 工程に入りました。分かったのは、システム設計担当といえど、 [off-by-oneエラー](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC) からは逃れられないということです。

Comment: 参考: 先に投稿してしまったので内容が重複していますが、こちらのメタ投稿に今年の帽子の情報が幾らかまとめてあります: https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2620/19110